# Is there a way to proactively load photos with Universal Image Loader?

Tags: java, android, gridview, lazy-loading, universal-image-loader

Is there a way to load the images that will come on the screen soon as opposed to loading the images that are currently in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to pre-load images so they are freshly cached, so that when the corresponding ImageView comes on screen the loading is nice and fast, you could use (somewhat untested):

```
String uri = getUriOfImageAboutToComeOnScreen(...);
ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(uri, null /* or use a listener */);
```

Of course, the magic contained in getUriOfImageAboutToComeOnScreen() is up to you :)

Comment: Ah, that second line should use loadImage, not displayImage:  ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(uri, listener); If you track actions via the listener you can see if the image is actually being requested and downloading completes.